# Why does PHP curl returns error 6 for one website?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to access [www.alberta.ca/](https://www.alberta.ca/) with PHP curl but it returns "Curl failed with error #6: Could not resolve host", although the website is online and returns a nice 200.

Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.alberta.ca/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

I tried all the solutions I could find, for example adding the following options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

But nothing works. Strangely, it works from my localhost, but not from my server.

Comment: You should talk to the server admin. They are in the best position to figure out what problem there might be with the local DNS provider resolving that host name.

Comment: Can you use the curl command to access the site on your server?

Comment: If you add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);` and run this from the CLI as a test, you will see you are getting a [`HTTP/2 301`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301)

Comment: @CBroe: I can't talk to the server admin, it's not my website

Comment: @shingo: I can't access the site from my server

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: I am not talking about the server admin of that website you are trying to curl (the problem is not on _their_ end), I am talking about the admin of what you yourself called "my server".

Comment: Tried WHAT? I only told you what the issue may be by showing you my test

Comment: @RiggsFolly: tried your test, and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @CBroe: thank you, I'll investigate on my server.

Comment: Who downvoted my question? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was on our server configuration, not our code.

Following @CBroe suggestion, we simply changed our DNS server and now it works.